# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Homebrewing's [2nd moderator election](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated:

[image: Lucas Kauffman] [image: Mr. Boy]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Answer (score 5):

No long acceptance speech from me...

I was primarily motivated to apply in the first place not because I had strong desires to be a moderator, but because there was a need and I think I can do an OK job, and it's good to pay back to SE after all it's given me.

So that's what I will set out to do! As a 1st-time moderator, I will initially set out to have a soft touch and tread lightly rather than be a bull in a china shop!

Thanks for the opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

This StackExchange moves forward because of you. It moves forward because you reaffirmed the alcohol spirit that has triumphed, the spirit that has lifted this place from the depths of despair to the great heights of hope, the belief that while each of us will pursue our own individual dreams, we are a Homebrewing family, and we rise or fall together as one community!